# Inheriting everything from base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, matrix

I have templated MxN matrix class

```
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix() { vecs_ = new Vector<T, N>[M]; }
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> l);
    Matrix(const Matrix& m);
    ~Matrix() { delete[] vecs_; }

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& m);
    Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix& m);
    Matrix& operator-=(const Matrix& m);
    Matrix& operator*=(T c);
    Matrix& operator/=(T c);

    Vector<T, N> operator[](int row) const;
    Vector<T, N>& operator[](int row);

    Vector<T, M> operator*(const Vector<T, N>& b) const;
    template<size_t P> Matrix<T, M, P> operator*(const Matrix<T, N, P>& b) const;

    Matrix<T, N, M> Transpose() const;

    size_t Rows() const { return M; }
    size_t Columns() const { return N; }
protected:
    Vector<T, N>* vecs_;
};

template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N> Matrix<T, M, N> operator+(const Matrix<T, M, N>& m) { return m; }
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N> Matrix<T, M, N> operator-(const Matrix<T, M, N>& m) { return Matrix<T, M, N>() - m; }

template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N> Matrix<T, M, N> operator+(const Matrix<T, M, N>& a, const Matrix<T, M, N>& b) { return a += b; }
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N> Matrix<T, M, N> operator-(const Matrix<T, M, N>& a, const Matrix<T, M, N>& b) { return a -= b; }

template<typename T, typename U, size_t M, size_t N> Matrix<T, M, N> operator*(Matrix<T, M, N> m, U c) { return m *= c; }
template<typename T, typename U, size_t M, size_t N> Matrix<T, M, N> operator*(U c, Matrix<T, M, N> m) { return m *= c; }

template<typename T, typename U, size_t M, size_t N> Matrix<T, M, N> operator/(Matrix<T, M, N> m, U c) { return m /= c; }

template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix<T, M, N>& m) { ... }
```

I wish to create NxN square matrix class that is derived from MxN matrix. This child class should inherit everything the parent have, including its operator overloads. This is what I tried

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class SquareMatrix : public Matrix<T, N, N>
{
public:
    using Matrix<T, N, N>::Matrix;    // inherit all constructors from the base class
    using Matrix<T, N, N>::operator=; // also inherit other operators
    using Matrix<T, N, N>::operator+=;
    using Matrix<T, N, N>::operator-=;
    using Matrix<T, N, N>::operator*=;
    using Matrix<T, N, N>::operator/=;
    using Matrix<T, N, N>::operator*;

    SquareMatrix(bool identity);
};
```

Is it a proper way to inherit? Are there any redundant lines? Is there anything else I need to add?

Also, I have problems with `*` and `[]` operator. In the parent matrix class, I have two overloads for each of these operators, each takes different parameter. Is there any way to distinguish between these two in the child square matrix class? `using Matrix<T, N, N>::operator*;` is bit ambiguous to compile.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Square matrices should be represented with  a specialisation of Matrix rather than with a derived class. If you need members exclusive to the specialisation, such as determinant calculations, just add them to the specialisation.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. By specialization, you mean an independent class? Then what about important functions like addition, multiplication, subtraction, etc? Do I need to rewrite everything for this class?

Comment: I mean a template specialisation.. It is possible to combine specialization and inheritance in order to not repeat stuff from the general template.  [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ej44o77qT) is one way to do this (very simplified code skeleton). Note the inheritance is private and it is here pure to inherit implementations. The derived class will have to add `using` declarations to expose methods from the parent class. Most of your operators need to be friends, these fo not need `using`. You could use public inheritance instead and omit `using` but IMO potential problems outweigh convenience.

Comment: *Is it a proper way to inherit?*  In my opinion, **no**, because `Matrix` was not designed to be *inherited from*, and as such probably ought to be tagged `final`.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine all your functions work with matrices of arbitary sizes right? If i manually declare 2 square matricies:

```
Matrix<int, 5, 5> m1, m2;
```

Do operations work on them? If so, then you don't need inheritance, you just need to make it easy for the user to make this specific version of the matrix type, which you can achieve with a type alias:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
using SquareMatrix = Matrix<T, N, N>;
```

And everything should just work.

---

If you want to add functions that are specific to the square matrix, aim to make them free functions:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr SquareMatrix<T, N> identity() noexcept {
   ...
}
```

This gives you a nice abstraction and is very modern c++ style. AKA, a matrix could easily be set as follows:

```
auto m = matrix::identity<int, 5>();
```

Comment: Hmm, that could work but I want to add member functions that are applicable to square matrixes only like `SetIdentity`, `CalculateDeterminant`, `Inverse`, etc.

Comment: Added an edit for you